# iOS voiceover in web view creates Shadow Content (User Agent)

Tags: html, web, webview, safari, wai-aria

When I turn on voiceover and focus over the image I see "Shadow Content (User Agent)" appear in the dom and voice over will read out a few more divs inside of that shadow dom. I've tried adding aria-label on both the img and the outer class, but it still reads the contents in the shadow dom. A work around I am doing is adding attribute "role=banner" since it is a logo and fits the banner description under wai-aria recommendations.

Does anyone know how to fix this or is this expected behavior for Safari?

```
<div class="org-logo">
    <img class="org-logo__image" src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
        > Shadow Content (User Agent)
    </img>
</div>
```

Comment: That sounds like a Safari bug that should be reported, or already might be. Safari is known for lagging behind in support of certain features.

Comment: I recommend reading [WebAIM’s guideline on alternative text for logos](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#logos). "Logo" is not very helpful. Convention is to link the logo to the home page, is that not the case here?
Where did you add the role="banner"? It’s very weird that this solves your issue, as that role should not change interpretation of the element’s contents.

Comment: It seems weird to me that Safari would create shadow content inside an image! Can you reproduce the issue in a clean Safari installation, without any extensions etc.?